How can I decorate org-mode quotes from `.emacs`, not per file?
In programming modes anything between quotation marks can be made to use a specific face by a simple switch.
(global-font-lock-mode t)

This is so nice to have that I'd like to duplicate it in org-mode.
I can decorate quotes (anywhere: org-mode, but also text-mode, etc) using font-lock, on a per-file basis.
Hi-lock: (("\"\\(.*?\\)\"" (0 (quote font-lock-string-face) t)))

How can I decorate org-mode quotes from .emacs, not per file?
Related

How to make orgmode decorate quotes?


Strange regexp: I don't understand how .*?  is different from .*. AFAICT, they both match zero or more non-newline characters - no?

@NickD .* is .*: any number of characters. The added ? makes it non-greedy. I can't quite recall an example where greediness here is undesirable, but at some point, after some incremental improvements, I thought it helps solve some boundary cases.

Ah, yes - I was confused.
